# Fan fiction where Harry Potter is wrongly sent to Azkaban

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, azkaban

I'm looking for a fan fiction story where Harry Potter is wrongly sent to Azkaban for a crime he didn't do.

No one believes him except Fred and George, who at one point even tried to break into Azkaban themselves to free him. New evidence comes to light and Dumbledore tells everyone Harry is innocent and they bring Harry back to Grimmauld Place and he's basically Catatonic but eventually wakes up.

When he is back to being sane, Dumbledore immediately wants Harry to help stop Voldemort since he's the boy who lived, except Harry wants no part in this.

Fred and George take Harry to their shop in Diagon Alley where they live and help him out.

In this story Dumbledore is still alive and wants to immediately use Harry to stop Voldemort even though he has just spent all this time in Azkaban. Sirius is alive too.

Again a main part of this story is that Fred and George help Harry. They have belived in his innocence all this time and now that they were right they aren't very happy with Dumbledore and the order

Comment: It's possible it's in this list of Harry Potter fan fiction related to Azkaban and betrayal: https://www.fanfiction.net/community/Azkaban-and-Betrayal/12228/ I'd give you a more concrete answer but there's a surprising amount of fanfiction where Harry is wrongfully imprisoned - hopefully one of them will seem familiar.

Comment: This is a pretty common theme. Do you remember anything else? Were there any romantic pairings? Any other significant deviations from the book like different people dying, different forms of magic, or new characters?

Comment: @derivative: Nothing surprises me in the HP fanfiction world any more.  There's so *much* of it that almost any plot you can describe in a few words has "a surprising amount of fanfiction" matching it.

Comment: I am looking for this exact same story! After the twins help him get out of grimmauld place, harry runs into the Prewett twins and then we discover that they had survived the first war with memory loss and one of them is married with children and harry becomes pen pals with the daughter while she is attending hogwarts and one of the sons really dislikes harry and the other one wants to be brave and fight like him. I remember him saying at one point that he wasn't sure if harry possessed 'bravery or stupidity'. There's this whole scene where death eaters attack kings cross station and harry lea

Answer (score 2):

As per my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187382/harry-potter-azkaban-fanfiction/187447#187447), this matches up with "[Road to Recovery](http://fanfics.me/read2.php?id=35800&chapter=1)" by cywsaphyre. It has a catatonic Harry being recovered from Azkaban. [The twins did try to break him out](http://fanfics.me/read2.php?id=35800&chapter=5).

> They fell silent when Harry finally put aside the empty bowl, observing him anxiously. Harry looked back at them, resting an arm on a raised knee.
>
> "You really tried... to break me out?" Harry asked at last.
>
> George exchanged a glance with his twin. "Well yeah," He nodded, leaning forward a little. "You weren't supposed to be in there."
>
> Fred looked rueful as he flopped onto his back. "Didn't work though, and we couldn't try again. We weighed our chances of course, but the probability of getting caught was too high."

In case the comment gets deleted, the original querent informally accepted this answer:

> Someone did end up finding the link for me, and it is the "Road To Recovery" one: fanfics.me/read2.php?id=35800&chapter=1 – *Aa Mm May 11 at 16:08*

Comment: Someone did end up finding the link for me, and it *is* the "Road To Recovery" one: http://fanfics.me/read2.php?id=35800&chapter=1